# Efficient Django query to include the primary contact from a list of Employers

Tags: django

I have a list of employers, each of which have multiple contacts.  One of those contacts may have been designated as primary for that organization.

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    pass

class EmployerContact(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need to display a list of employers and their primary contacts.

If I use `Employer.objects.all()`, I get all of them but then need an extra query to get the primary contact per employer, on a long list, this is not very efficient.

If I select on primary contacts and `.select_related('employer')` I get all the employers that have primary contacts, but miss those that don't have any contact (or maybe a primary contact has not yet been selected).

How can I get the list of Employers with their primary contact efficiently without missing employers with no primary contact?

Is there someway using `.extra` maybe?

Comment: Have you tried with `Q` object? Suppose your `employer` field related name is `contact`, probably you can do something like `Employer.objects.filter(Q(contact__primary=True) | Q(contact__isnull=True))`

Comment: Oh and you need to add `.select_related('contact')` of course. If you print sql produced by the orm, you'll see that it'll issue a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, that is what you need. Let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) (which allows you to cache relationships that `select_related` can't) to first fetch and cache the related `EmployeeContact` objects, and then do the logic for finding if they have `primary=True` or not in python.

This would do it in two queries:

```
employees = Employee.objects.all().prefetch_related("employeecontact_set")
l = []
for e in employees:
    for c in e.employeecontact_set.all():
        if c.primary:
            l.append(e.pk)
employees = employees.filter(pk__in=l)
```

Comment: I hadn't read that part of the docs since 1.2.  prefetch_related makes a HUGE difference.  Thanks